# Complex Nature of the Wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, complex-numbers

I am doing this problem and I realized the wavefunction is real. But we also already showed that the wavefunction needs to be complex. Why is it that the wavefunction given here is real? I first taught $N$ could be complex, but it cannot since when you compute it to normalize $\Psi (\mathbf{x})$, it is a function of $a_o$ and $r$ which are both reals.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrogen ground state identified by quantum numbers $(n=1,\ell =0,m=0)$ has no dependancy on [phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_factor), so ground state has phase factor $e^{i \phi} = 1$. However for other Hydrogen energy levels situation can be different. For example Hydrogen state identified with quantum numbers $(2,1,\pm 1)$ **does depend** on phase and as such state's wavefunction has full complex form :

$$ \psi _{2,1,\pm 1}=\mp {\frac {1}{8{\sqrt {\pi }}a_{0}^{3/2}}}{\frac {r}{a_{0}}}e^{-r/2a_{0}}\sin \theta ~e^{\pm i\phi } $$

Comment: This was really helpful. It is in fact a consequence of the atom being at ground state, not only that it is the time-independent wavefunction.

Answer (score 2):

It is complex, just with the imaginary component being zero.

Comment: if you think this way, then all real numbers are complex, with imaginary part being zero. Isn't it just simpler to say that it belongs to real class of numbers ?

Comment: Nice answer (yes, it is really a complete answer in this case!).

Comment: But that's how it works. All natural numbers are whole numbers, are rational numbers, are real numbers are complax numbers. Just the reverse it not true.

Answer (score 2):

An eigenfunction like the hydrogen ground state referred to in the question separates into time and space parts:

$$ \Psi(r,\theta,\phi,t) = \psi(r,\theta,\phi) ~ e^{-iEt/\hbar} $$

where $E$ is the energy of the state. However the exponential part isn't a physical observable so we tend to ignore it and just write:

$$ \Psi(r,\theta,\phi,t) = \psi(r,\theta,\phi) $$

In the case of the hydrogen ground state $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)$ is real, but this is only part of the wavefunction and the whole wavefunction is complex.

Comment: It might also be worth noting that energy eigenfunctions can always be assumed to be real-valued functions;  we don't have to worry that $\psi$ itself is complex. This follows from the Hermiticity of the Hamiltonian (or, if you prefer, the properties of Schrödinger's equations viewed as a differential equation.)

Answer (score 2):

If you define the spatial probability density $\rho(x,t) = \psi^*(x,t)\psi(x,t)$ and compute its derivative with respect to time, you obtain after some algebra

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left[\frac{i\hbar}{2m} \left(\frac{\partial \psi^*}{\partial x}\psi - \psi^* \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}\right)\right]\equiv -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} J$$

where $J(x,t)$ is called the probability current.  It obeys a continuity equation $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial J}{\partial x} = 0$, which means that if $\rho$ changes in some region, then there must be some flux of $J$ through the region's boundary.  You can think of it as being the probability-oriented counterpart to the familiar charge/current continuity equation for electromagnetism.

If you write $\psi(x,t) = \alpha(x,t) e^{i\phi(x,t)}$ where both $\alpha(x,t)$ and $\phi(x,t)$ are real (we can always do this) and plug the result into the expression for $J$, we find that

$$J(x,t) = \frac{\hbar \alpha}{m} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$$

The interpretation is that spatial variations in the wavefunction's phase correspond to a non-zero probability current.

---

You can always multiply any element of the Hilbert space by a global phase factor, so you can take a purely real wavefunction and make it complex by multiplying it by $i$. However, in order to have a fully real $\psi$ in the first place, it must be that the phase is spatially constant - meaning that the probability current must vanish.

In 1D, this is always true of energy eigenfunctions$^\dagger$ (disregarding the trivial $e^{-iEt/\hbar}$ factor which arises from time-evolution).  One can see this by noting that since $\rho$ is constant in time for such states, $\frac{\partial J}{\partial x}=0$; from there, since an energy eigenfunction must be normalizable, it follows that $A\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$ so $J=0$ everywhere.

In higher dimensions, $\nabla \cdot \mathbf J = 0$ does not imply that $\mathbf J=0$.  In particular, when a state has angular momentum about some axis, there will be a non-vanishing probability current corresponding to an angular "flow".  However, when angular momentum is not present (as is the case for $m=0$ orbitals, then the probability current vanishes, as does the spatial variation of the phase.

$^\dagger$As a side note, this is **not** true of "generalized" (i.e. non-normalizable) eigenfunctions, like those of the free particle on a line.